# How do I access an entire website list that is continually generated when scrolling?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, search, optimization

I am trying to acquire all the information from a list of songs on ranker, however as I keep scrolling down new songs appear in an ever growing list, as the name suggests its a voting website so I am guessing at some point the list will end. Is there a way to show the entire list without having to keep scroll down and save it into a text doc.

I figured this was the best place to ask this question, if not let me know where else would be suitable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about creating, maintaining, or marketing your own website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not right place of your question, you can ask this question stackoverflow community of developers.

However, answer to your question is no it is not possible as content appearing is dynamic which coming from database.

Comment: Why wouldn't dynamic content be crawlable? You can check which backend call is being performed and write something to loop over that with different id's/offsets.